# Wrong redirect_uri on keycloak

Tags: nginx, tomcat8, keycloak

I am trying to use keycloak to authenticate my service that are provided in a tomcat 8 docker by following https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/tomcat-adapter.adoc

After i finished to configure my application it redirected correctly to the keycloak server however the redirect_uri was wrong since was calling an internal address only known by docker: hxxps://****.pt/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=appmovel&**redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fweb-service%3A8080**%2F&state=...

In order to fix it i configured a nginx to correct the redirect_uri

```
location /admin/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://web-service:8080/;
    }
```

resulting in: hxxps://****.pt/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=appmovel&**redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnewservice***%2F&state=...

However the redirect_uri skips the context /admin/ resulting in bad redirection since it was supposed to redirect to: ***http%3A%2F%2Fnewservice%2Fadmin***%2F&state=...

How and where should i configure to keep/add the context (/admin) in the redirect_uri ? Should be a keycloak configuration or a nginx rewrite rule ?

Comment: did you solve this issue? I am stuck at the same problem